# Dictionary uses object as key. The key is updated outside the dictionary

Tags: c#

Consider a simple class:

```
public class TestClass<Val>
{
    public Val Value{get;set;}
}
```

Create an instance of this class and define a dictionary where we use it as a key.

```
TestClass<int> TestCase = new TestClass<int>();
Dictionary<TestClass<int>, int> D = new Dictionary<TestClass<int>, int>();
```

Put 0 into the TestCase and add the entry to dictionary:

```
TestCase.Value=0
D.Add(TestCase,10)
```

Now the dictionary looks like this: {TestCase -> Value=0:10}
Now do this:

```
TestCase.Value=1
```

Now I have in the dictionary {TestCase -> Value=1 : 10} automatically, without putting the key 'TestCase -> Value=1' into the dictionary. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Remember to implement `Equals` and [`GetHashCode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) in your class if you want to use it as key in a dictionary.

Comment: @Tim actually, at the moment this is just a cosmetic issue; if you implement `Equals` / `GetHashCode` on that, it could become a deeply functional issue, breaking the dictionary. I agree it should *have* those methods, but that should ideally only be applied at the same time as making the key-type immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create immutable `TestCase` class:

```
public class TestClass<Val>
{
    public TestClass(Val value)
    {
       Value = value;
    }

    public Val Value{ get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: but in this case I can't use TestCase.Value=0 and need to create TestCase each time once again like TestCase<int>=new TestCase<int>(0) would it be ok if the loop is big enough?

Comment: You can't use one object for different keys in dictionary - anyway you need to create new keys

Answer (score 4):

Basically, don't use mutable types as keys... or if you do, make sure you never mutate the key. The first would be preferable.

An even bigger problem is that if `TestClass<Val>` has a custom `GetHashCode()` / `Equals()` implementation, you can completely break the dictionary, as it may no longer be able to find a value for that key, **even if you give it the exact instance you started with**.

Anything you use as a key should ideally be immutable. For that reason, `int` and `string` make great choices, but you can also just make your type immutable, as per @lazyberezovsky's example.

Comment: as you said, the next problem I faced with was that it wasn't possible to find a value for that key given the same instance, so I had to add the Equals() and GetHashCode() to the class

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is one single instance of TestClass. You created it outside dictionary and then added that instance to dictionary.

If you make changes to instance it reflects inside dictionary. This is shallow copying

To avoid this problem create a deepclone of your instance and then add in dictionary. In that case changes in one will not be reflected in another.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I need to create a method DeepCopy inside the TestClass class as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx , where I use MemberCloneWise and copy class members to a new class. What do you think is faster to make deep copies or to create new instance as @lazyberezovsky suggests?